# fbAsyncInit event listener not firing full function

Tags: jquery, facebook, wordpress, api, facebook-graph-api

I am running into an issue with fbAsyncInit not running the entire function it is supposed to. Below is where I have added the event listener in the asyncinit call. If I simply try to run the function on document.ready, I receive and error saying FB is undefined. Unfortunately, I had to add the event listener to the code of the plugin I am using (WP-FB-AutoConnect). I know this is bad practice but it's the only way it seems to manipulate the init call. Meaning the However I am not sure this is the issue because if I add something like an alert instead, it fires. Below is where I have added the event listener in the init call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<!--
  window.fbAsyncInit = function()
  {
    FB.init({
        appId: '<?php echo get_option($opt_jfb_app_id); ?>',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true,
        channelUrl: '<?php echo $channelURL; ?>' 
    });
    $(document).trigger('fbload');
    <?php do_action('wpfb_add_to_asyncinit'); ?>            
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo apply_filters('wpfb_output_facebook_locale', 'en_US'); ?>/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
//--></script>
```

Here is the js/jquery on the page I am writing.

```
 function facebook_ratings() {
            console.log('from fbload');

            var fb_page_id = $('#fb-page-id').val();
            var fb_page_token = $('#fb-page-access_token').val();

            FB.api(
                "/"+fb_page_id+"/ratings",
                {
                    access_token: fb_page_token,
                },
                function (response) {
                  if (response && !response.error) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    console.log('response', response);

                    var average = 0;

                    for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        average += response.data[i].rating;
                        console.log('reviewer name', response.data[i].reviewer.name);
                        console.log('reviewer id', response.data[i].reviewer.id);
                        console.log('message', response.data[i].review_text);
                        console.log('\n');
                    }
                    average = average/response.data.length;
                    console.log('average', average.toFixed(2));

                  }
                  else {
                    console.log(response.error);
                  }
                });
        };

        $(document).on('fbload', facebook_ratings());
```

When I load the page, the only thing returned is the very first console log or anything before FB.api(). Also, I am sure that the facebook_ratings() function works because I can use it in other contexts. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I found a action to add the jquery in the init call. So now I don't have to mess with the plugin code, but nonetheless I am not seeing any difference.

Comment: did you view source to see if all the php variables are correct? It sounds like there is a error or else no response is generated. it would be more useful to include the code from the source if not one of the above

Comment: Yes, my variables are right. I am able to use the function if I call it say from a click event or something and it works. So I know that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the easiest way to fix my issue was to have to code within $(window).load(function(){}. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WordPress, the jQuery implementation is slightly different. Try changing:

```
$(document).trigger('fbload');
```

to:

```
jQuery(document).trigger('fbload');
```

Basically, you'll need to replace `$` with `jQuery` in order for jQuery to correctly work. However, this is only needed if you are using the WordPress version of jQuery.

Comment: Unfortunately, that made no difference :(